# how to simplify or combine 2 jquery pullout functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a simple page with 2 pullout functions, one on the left and one on the right side. I would like to simplify or combine the two functions into one and make one pullout close, when I click on the other one, so that only one can be seen at a time.

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#clickme").click(function () {
        if($(this).parent().hasClass("popped")){
        $(this).parent().animate({left:'-750px'}, {queue: false, duration: 400}).removeClass("popped");
        $(".overlay").fadeOut(500);
    }else {
        $(this).parent().animate({left: "0px" }, {queue: false, duration: 400}).addClass("popped");
        $(".overlay").fadeIn(500);
        }
    });

    $(".overlay").click(function(){
        $("#clickme").click();
    });


    $("#clickme2").click(function () {
        if($(this).parent().hasClass("popped")){
        $(this).parent().animate({right:'-750px'}, {queue: false, duration: 400}).removeClass("popped");
        $(".overlay2").fadeOut(500);
    }else {
        $(this).parent().animate({right: "0px" }, {queue: false, duration: 400}).addClass("popped");
        $(".overlay2").fadeIn(500);
        }
    });

    $(".overlay2").click(function(){
        $("#clickme2").click();
    });

});
```

**CSS**

```
#slideout, #slideout2 {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    position: fixed;
    width: 750px;
    height: auto;
    top: 20%;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    z-index:9999;
}

#slideout {
    left:-750px;
}

#slideout2 {
    top: 40%;
    right: -750px;
} 

#clickme, #clickme2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 102px;
    width: 184px;
    background: url(../../assets/images/pullout.png) top left no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.2s 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s 1s ease-in-out;

}

#clickme {
    right: -184px;
}

#clickme2 {
    background: url(../../assets/images/pullout2.png) top left no-repeat;
    left: -184px;
}

#slidecontent, #slidecontent2 {
    float: left;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 28px;
    padding: 25px;
}

#slidecontent p, #slidecontent2 p {
    padding: 0 10px;
}


#slideout.popped, #slideout2.popped {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}

#slideout.popped #clickme, #slideout2.popped #clickme2 {
    background-position: 0 -103px;
}

.overlay, .overlay2 {
    display:none;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.65;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 65); /* IE7 & 8 */
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 49;
    background-color: #000;
    cursor:pointer;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- Gutschein Pullout Start 1 -->
<div class="overlay"> &nbsp;</div>

<div id="slideout">
    <div id="slidecontent">
        <a href="assets/images/Lenz_Massivholz_Gewinn-Karte_15-04_WEB.pdf" target="_blank">
            <img src="assets/images/Lenz_Massivholz_Gewinn-Karte_15-04_WEB.jpg" width="600" height="426" alt="Jetzt Teilnahmekarte anklicken, ausdrucken und ausfüllen">
        </a>
        <p style="margin:5px 0 15px;">Einfach auf die Teilnahmekarte klicken und die Grafik ausdrucken und ausfülen. Anschließend beim nächsten Einkauf bei <b>Möbel Lenz</b> abgeben und mit etwas Glück gewinnen.</p>
        <p style="font-size: 12px; font-style:italic;">*  Nur eine Teilnahmekarte pro Person einlösbar.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="clickme"></div>
</div>
<!-- Gutschein Pullout Ende 1 -->

<!-- Gutschein Pullout Start 2 -->
<div class="overlay2"> &nbsp;</div>

<div id="slideout2">
    <div id="slidecontent2">
        <a href="assets/images/Lenz_Massivholz_GUT-Blume_15-04_WEB.pdf" target="_blank">
            <img src="assets/images/Lenz_Massivholz_GUT-Blume_15-04_WEB.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="Jetzt Gutschein anklicken und ausdrucken">
        </a>
        <p style="margin:5px 0 15px;">Einfach auf den Gutschein klicken und die Grafik ausdrucken, oder herunterladen. Anschließend beim nächsten Einkauf bei <b>Möbel Lenz</b> vorzeigen einen Frühlingsblüher mitnehmen.</p>
        <p style="font-size: 12px; font-style:italic;">*  Nur ein Gutschein pro Person einlösbar.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="clickme2"></div>
</div>
<!-- Gutschein Pullout Ende 2 -->
```

You can see the live version here:
http://lenz.eprospekt.info

Answer (score 0):

instead of using id's use classes. `#clickme1` and `#clickme2` Just use a class `.clickme`. In your jQuery selector replace the id with `.clickme`. Then get rid of the second function.

EDIT: Keep ID's for styling purposes.

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
$(".clickme").click(function () {
    if($(this).parent().hasClass("popped")){
        $(this).parent().animate({left:'-750px'}, {queue: false, duration: 400}).removeClass("popped");
        $(".overlay").fadeOut(500);
    }else {
        $(this).parent().animate({left: "0px" }, {queue: false, duration: 400}).addClass("popped");
          $(".overlay").fadeIn(500);
        }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- Gutschein Pullout Start 1 -->
<div class="overlay"> &nbsp;</div>

<div id="slideout">
    <div id="slidecontent">
        <a href="assets/images/Lenz_Massivholz_Gewinn-Karte_15-04_WEB.pdf" target="_blank">
            <img src="assets/images/Lenz_Massivholz_Gewinn-Karte_15-04_WEB.jpg" width="600" height="426" alt="Jetzt Teilnahmekarte anklicken, ausdrucken und ausfüllen">
        </a>
        <p style="margin:5px 0 15px;">Einfach auf die Teilnahmekarte klicken und die Grafik ausdrucken und ausfülen. Anschließend beim nächsten Einkauf bei <b>Möbel Lenz</b> abgeben und mit etwas Glück gewinnen.</p>
        <p style="font-size: 12px; font-style:italic;">*  Nur eine Teilnahmekarte pro Person einlösbar.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="clickme1" class="clickme"></div>
</div>
<!-- Gutschein Pullout Ende 1 -->

<!-- Gutschein Pullout Start 2 -->
<div class="overlay2"> &nbsp;</div>

<div id="slideout2">
    <div id="slidecontent2">
        <a href="assets/images/Lenz_Massivholz_GUT-Blume_15-04_WEB.pdf" target="_blank">
            <img src="assets/images/Lenz_Massivholz_GUT-Blume_15-04_WEB.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="Jetzt Gutschein anklicken und ausdrucken">
        </a>
        <p style="margin:5px 0 15px;">Einfach auf den Gutschein klicken und die Grafik ausdrucken, oder herunterladen. Anschließend beim nächsten Einkauf bei <b>Möbel Lenz</b> vorzeigen einen Frühlingsblüher mitnehmen.</p>
        <p style="font-size: 12px; font-style:italic;">*  Nur ein Gutschein pro Person einlösbar.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="clickme2" class="clickme"></div>
</div>
<!-- Gutschein Pullout Ende 2 -->
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I see what you are trying, but it seems like it does not work too well. here is a test version: http://lenz.eprospekt.info/test/

Comment: Keep the id's of `#clickme1` && `#clickme2` for styling purpose.  Then you should be good. Don't change your jQuery selector back though. @Supapinzi

Comment: I have added a fiddle so it is easier to understand. Actually I changed it a little bit, so that both pullouts remain underneath each others on the left side. ultimately I'd like to make the inactive pullouts invisible when one pullout is clicked and only have them return to visibility when the active pullout is closed.
http://jsfiddle.net/schakalwal/gwu2gob3/